# Cannot import Sequential Model from keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am getting the following error when executing the following statement

`from keras.models import Sequential`

`cannot import name 'context' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (unknown location)`

Please note that I have tried all answers which were available on Stack Overflow but could not solve my problem.

If anyone has faced a similar issue and solved it please revert back

Comment: try: from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade your keras and tensorflow to current versions